# PrestaShopDatabaseException MySQL server has gone away after moving to VPS

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, prestashop

I've recently migrated a shop from shared server to VPS. Copied all files to the new server and imported the database. Completed the initial set ups. Now the homepage of the site is loading, but all other pages showing database exception. It is showing a long query. Can someone suggest me something. My mysql connect timeout is 60 secs. The query is so long that posting here freezes the browser. I'm posting an exrept of that sql query. Can someone suggest me something over this ?

```
SELECT product_shop.id_product, MAX(product_attribute_shop.id_product_attribute) id_product_attribute
                    FROM `awfps_product` p
                     INNER JOIN awfps_product_shop product_shop
        ON (product_shop.id_product = p.id_product AND product_shop.id_shop = 1)
                    LEFT JOIN  `awfps_product_attribute` pa ON (product_shop.id_product = pa.id_product)
                     LEFT JOIN awfps_product_attribute_shop product_attribute_shop
        ON (product_attribute_shop.id_product_attribute = pa.id_product_attribute AND product_attribute_shop.id_shop = 1 AND product_attribute_shop.default_on = 1)
                    WHERE product_shop.`active` = 1
                         AND (( product_shop.`id_product` = 38) OR( product_shop.`id_product` = 40) OR( product_shop.`id_product` = 41)................all products
                        AND p.`id_product` IN (
                            SELECT cp.`id_product`
                            FROM `awfps_category_group` cg
                            LEFT JOIN `awfps_category_product` cp ON (cp.`id_category` = cg.`id_category`)
                            WHERE cg.`id_group` IN (3)
                        )
                     AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "catalog")
                    GROUP BY product_shop.id_product
                    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I searched for the bug in debugging tool and found some clues. The error was for special blocks module. When you have a lot of products in the special category or in other words if you have applied catalog price discount to a lot of products then the special block module retrieves all products with the same category and chooses a particular to show in the special block. Disabled it and it's working. This part of the code may need to be modified. I've tried to create an issue but didn't succeeded when writing this post. May create that later.